# NextJS + SSR + IIS deployment

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, next.js, web-config

https://youtu.be/HLsx0iraA-Y?t=619

I've been using this video to set it up but I'm wondering if I can just run `next start`
and have that be the node server instead of my own custom server.

I see that the web.config file points to the server.js file (custom server) as an entry/starting point and if I do next start it wont have that configuration.

So is there any way I can just use next.js next start to start my server instead of have my own custom server but still have it be deployed on IIS?

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779064/deploying-next-js-project-in-iis

Comment: I followed this when I was initially setting it all up. 

I got it working but the problem was that it had a really long cold start. (assume its because of all the node_modules it needs) and i gave up.  =/