# Can't get .css and .js files while hosting next js application on IIS

Tags: iis, next.js, deployment

I have some problem with getting .css and .js files of my site when I try to open my hosted site.
My site is the next js application and hosted on IIS server. Please note that I am not a javascript developer and it is my first experiance in deploying next js application)).

Requests loock like this:
[Site requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ytNj.png)

And single rquest loock like this:
[Single one request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQBLb.png)

When I deployed to IIS, I configured the following web.config and server.js.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

    <webSocket enabled="false" />

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>


        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url=".next/static"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <iisnode 
        watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;node_modules\*;"
        node_env="production"
        />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

server.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }).listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on ')
  })
})
```

In my opinion, the problem is related to the availability of static files, but I do not understand how to configure them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for 404.
If it is your first experiance in deploying next js application. You can refer to this answer about **Deploying Next Js project in IIS**. It needs NodeJS, URLRewrite and IISNode on your server.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67212396/20058276

Importantly, iisnode is out of maintenance for a long time. You can try to use HttpPlatformHandler. https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/.
This tutorial document is from Lex Li. Perhaps this article can provide better help.