# Publishing NextJS to IIS

Tags: iis, next.js

I'm trying to publish a NextJS website on IIS, I've already installed [URL Rewrite](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases/tag/v0.2.21) and [IIS Node](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) on the server, I tried following [this guide to set up a reverse proxy](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy), but that didn't seem to work, as even though I was running the project on the server, it wasn't redirecting to it.

I then tried [hosting with a custom server](https://noobgrammer.com/2022/01/20/deploy-nextjs-to-azure-web-service-iis/), this works when running locally, but when run `next build`, copy the generated .next folder, package.json, web.config, and server.js onto the server where IIS is being hosted, running `node server.js` doesn't seem to work, as it simply stops after:

```
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
```

No other question or blog I see seems to cover hosting on a different computer than the one used to develop, so I'm not clear on whether or not I'm simply supposed to copy the entire source code to the production server, and run `next start` there, that would not seem ideal.

Comment: In general, Node.js based applications can be deployed via HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ Note that reverse proxy/IISNode should also work, but you probably hit badly written guides.

Comment: To configure IIS as a reverse proxy, you need to install the URL Rewrite and ARR . The URL Rewrite extension allows you to define rules, and the ARR extension supports  load balancing, rule-based routing, and more. You can refer to this tutorial: https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Answer (score 1):

> Finally have some time to revisit this. So expand my comment above.

Assuming you use the official sample from Next.js, you just need the following steps,

1. Install HttpPlatformHandler.
2. `npm run build` to create production artifacts.
3. Add a web.config file as below.
4. Go to IIS Manager and create a site to point to this source folder.

Literally it is equivalent to running `npm run start`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="<some path>\node.exe" arguments=".\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next start">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can delete unnecessary files from the source folder, and leaving only `.next`, `node_modules`, and `web.config`.

### Reference

https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs