# Deploying Next.js on IIS

Tags: iis, next.js, deployment

I've been trying to deploy a next.js project on IIS. I've done a couple of tests and I've also created some smaller nextjs projects to test different strategies. I'm completely new to this but it's a requirement so I'm trying to make it work.

What I've done so far:

I've build the project with next build and I then copied the .next folder, the node_modules folder to a new folder together with a web.config and a server.js which I found online on a medium guide. I've also installed the modules `iisnode` and `URLRewrite`. I then added an application under Default Web Site under Sites, that sits under an application pool in IIS. The application's physical pth is to the build folder that contains the previously listed files. I've made sure that the user has all the rights on the application pool and the application.

When I start the application I get the (nextjs) `404 | This page could not be found.` screen. The route is `http://localhost/iis-test-project`. I've also tried to set the `next.config.js` to `output: "export"` and copy the output file instead of the `.next file`.

Besides the 404 on the `localhost/iis-test-project` I also see some 404s on other content in from the .next folder like  `http://localhost/_next/static/chunks/main-app-9fe887c4b47d5643.js`

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Server.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: The original developers leave no guide on how to deploy to IIS and issues like https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56384 opened, so I don't think you should waste your time on IIS.

Comment: If you want to solve the 404 error, you can try to use failed request tracing to see the specific cause of the error.

Comment: Turn out just a few simple steps are needed, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823437/11182

Answer (score 0):

u can try this in Server.js:

```js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```